# return different linq to sql result sets into single object(json format)?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Example:

context means Instance of dbml.

```
var lst1 = context.Customers.AsQuerable();

var lst2 = context.Products.AsQuerable();

var lst3 = context.Employees.AsQuerable();
```

how do i return these three different result sets into single object?

i need like this type :

```
var lstFinalResult = lst1 + lst2 + lst3;
```

I'm using Linq to sql and c#.

Please any one can give the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use anonymus types. something like this

```
var somethingJSON = new {
  list1Data= lst1 ,
  list2Data= lst2,
list3Data= lst3
};

return JSON(somethingJSON,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Hi Ravi thank u for giving the solution, but i'm not using mvc project it is wcf data service with linq to sql c#. and  give me solution.I have bll class in that i'll write all the logic and in my service just i call that method thats it. please if u have any idea about this.

Comment: then. use the anonymus types and parse it to JSON. same concept. just ignore the return JSON line.  then do your own JSON parsing